# iPhone - Change icon of the app programmatically at runtime

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, icons, springboard

I can read that changing the app icon programmatically at runtime is not possible, at least since iOS 3.0.

But... I regulary can see on "App" websites apps that can put icons on the springboard. The first I remember is that kind of app that you give a friend's picture from your album, and it creates an icon so you can call him just clicking on that icon:

http://itunes.apple.com/fr/app/speedtouch-the-best-home-screen/id378360978?mt=8
http://itunes.apple.com/fr/app/desktop-shortcut/id421701004?mt=8
http://itunes.apple.com/fr/app/appbutler-app-organizer/id327391626?mt=8
http://itunes.apple.com/fr/app/tap4music/id365578914?mt=8

So I guess, is it still impossible to change the app icon programmatically at runtime?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [iOS Changing App icon at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12191233/ios-changing-app-icon-at-runtime)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Update

Apple have changed this, you can do this now: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/2806818-setalternateiconname

#### Original Answer

> What you're thinking of here are WebClips, which are basically shortcuts to websites on the home screen. An actual application cannot change it's icon at runtime, as it's defined in the static Info.plist file.
>
> The only exception to this rule is Newsstand applications.

Comment: Making a call via a website ? Opening an iTunes album via a Website shortcut ? Can you explain how this can be done ? So then what about opening my app through a shortcut ?

Comment: You might be able to hack some redirects and respond to a custom URL scheme to make this open your app, but I've never tried anything like it before so I can't speak to its integrity.

Answer (score 1):

This is now possible in iOS 10.3 using the [`UIApplication.setAlternateIconName(_:completionHandler:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/2806818-setalternateiconname) API.

See my answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44966454/233602

Answer (score -1):

Changing your actual icon (other than, e.g, badging) would require changing the app bundle.  I'm pretty sure that you don't have write access to the bundle, and in any event this should change the code signature, causing the OS to prevent launching.

So, no.  Apps can put links to web sites, but not change their own app.

Comment: You're right, app bundles are read-only, due mostly to code-signing.