# iOS Changing App icon at runtime

Tags: ios, xcode

I want to change my app icon at runtime. I read other similar threads on SO, and they say that it is not possible using Apple sanctioned APIs. One of the responses mentioned that its possible using restricted APIs, but did not elaborate.

I understand that if I use restricted APIs, my application scope will be reduced to jail-broken devices only. I'm ok with that, but how do I implement this feature.

Sorry, I cannot indicate any research effort for this question because I have no idea how to go about it or even how to get started on this.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I am very interested in knowing how you came up with this requirement ?

Comment: Need to make a demo. Want to make it impressive. Device will be mine so its ok to have it working on a jail-broken device.

Comment: I am not sure about this and I have no idea whatsoever of how to achieve this. But, if you truly want to make it impressive focus on other features like UI, speed and how many clicks features are away. After all flashy stuff matter once.

Comment: @KishorKundan At a certain level I do agree with you. I will be considering those aspects for sure. But I believe in having the X-factor. If I can have something in my demo that few or nobody knows how its done, then that leaves a mark (even if I have to tell them later that its not possible in production app). If its possible, then I'm including this feature in my demo.

Comment: The calendar app that comes with ios devices has an icon that shows the current day, so it is theoretically possible.

Comment: Yes Victor, Calendar app is what gave me this idea. But I still don't have a clue how to go about it. Any pointers in this matter will be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although this is an old question, I recently discovered this is now possible, as of iOS 10.3:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/2806818-setalternateiconname

...using the `UIApplication.setAlternateIconName(_:completionHandler:)` API.

Note however you are limited to using icons which are already shipped as part of the app bundle.

Comment: Hi Andrew, this is not relevant for me anymore ofcourse, but good to know. Thanks for the tip. I assume it is now part of legal API, right?

Comment: Yes - completely legit API. 