# How can I change the app icon and name of an Ionic app during runtime?

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm trying to hide my app or change the icon and name after the user takes some action, I don't know if there's a way to do this because the main idea is the app looks unnoticed for other users besides the phone owner.

I've been reading some things about how to do this on android but I can't find anything on ionic or cordova, so I'm looking for some guidance to do this

I hope you can help me!

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand why you would need to change the app icon or name depending on what the user does, but even then, all of the things I have read conclude that there is no way to do this, at least on iOS.

You can check out some similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12191233/ios-changing-app-icon-at-runtime), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13005007/dynamic-icon-change-for-iphone) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2097807/dynamically-change-iphone-app-icon-and-loading-image). Although I must admit that these resources are quite outdated. Regarding your question, the only technology within Ionic that would be able to do this is Cordova and if it is not possible natively, which seems to be the case for iOS, then there is nothing that Cordova can do.

If you have found a way to do this on Android, then you would have to build your own Cordova plugin to handle it, because there doesn't seem to be anything out there that can do this.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this on iOS 10+. check this out:
https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-app-icon-changer

haven't been able to find a solution for Android yet, if it is possible at all.